# PrimeNg - Pesquisar por vários campos no Picklist

Tags: jquery, angular, primefaces, typescript

Estou usando o PickList numa app do Angular 7.
No Picklist, preciso fazer a pesquisa em mais de um campo exibido no container.

No site deles (PrimeNG) tem um exemplo: [PickListTutorial](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist)
Na tag, tem um campo chamado **filterBy="brand"** onde coloco o campo a ser filtrado, mas preciso informar mais campos nesta parte.

Tentei fazer assim **filterBy="brand, year, color"**, mas só pega o primeiro campo para fazer a busca.

Código do component.html.ts

```html
<p-pickList [source]="sourceCars" [target]="targetCars" sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true" filterBy="brand" 
        dragdrop="true" sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by brand" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by brand" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{car.brand}}.png" style="display:inline-block;margin:2px 0 2px 2px" width="48">
            <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{car.brand}} - {{car.year}} - {{car.color}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Código Component.ts

```js
export class PickListDemo {

    sourceCars: Car[];

    targetCars: Car[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.sourceCars = cars);
        this.targetCars = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Posta o código completo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta acrescentando o código lá @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho

Comment: Procurei no repositorio deles e realmente tá bugado, https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7121 , pode acompanhar essa issue ai e ver se tem algum prazo. mas infelizmente não vai ser com esse component que vai conseguir.

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho, eu tirei os espaços que tinha, e funcionou o filter! O EduardoVargas deu a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz sem espaços:  `filterBy="brand,year,color"`

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoVargas, funcionou!